Counterexample for Exercise 36 of Chapter 5 in Carothers
I am trying to solve Exercise 36 of Chapter 5 from Carothers' book.
Suppose that we are given a point $x$ and a sequence $(x_n)$ in a metric space $M$, and suppose that $f(x_n)$ tends to $f(x)$ for every continuous, real-valued function $f$ on $M$. Does it follow that $x_n$ tends to $x$ in $M$? Explain.
For the solution, I thought of the following, but I got stuck somewhere.
I believe that what the exercise states is not true, and I am trying to find a counterexample.
I considered the discrete real metric space and assumed $f: (\mathbb{R}, \delta) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \delta)$. Then, I considered $x_n =\frac{1}{n}$ and $x_0 = 0$. In the discrete metric space, since all sets are open and closed, then $f$ will be continuous. Thus, $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$. I am trying to show that $x_0 = 0$ because in this case, $x_n$ does not tend to $0$ in discrete metric space, and I have found the counterexample I am looking for.

The sequence does not converge to $x_0$: there does not exist any $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $\delta(x_n,x_0)\lt \frac{1}{2}$. And so the hypothesis is not met by taking $f$ to be the identity function.

The problem implicitly assumes the codomain of $f$ is always $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.

I'm not sure what you mean by "what the exercise states is not true." The exercise asks you whether a particular conclusion follows. It does not assert that it does, and does not assert that it does not.

@ArturoMagidin Yes, but we need to find a counterexample where $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ holds for every continuous real function, not just for the identity function. Am I thinking correctly?

The question is: if for every continuous function $f$, you have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$, does it follow that $x_n\to x$? Here you have a sequence for which the  premise, that for every continuous function you have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$, does not hold. That means that the sequence is irrelevant to the question.

Isn't the distance from $x$ a continuous function?

@Lieven So you mean that it holds true, and if we consider $f(x_n) = d(x_n, x)$, this will tend to $f(x) = d(x, x) = 0$, therefore $x_n$ will tend to $x$?

Yes, that was the idea.

thank you very much!
